# Tab bar limits?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any way to increase the number of items in the iphone tab bar beyond five? I know that it can create a "More..." tab, but it seems excessive for just one more tab.

I have an app which needs six (Alternatively I will have to do some deep meditation to get rid of one).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. This is a hard coded limit in the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. The [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW1) makes several references to only being able to display 5 tabs at a time.

If you *really* want this functionality, you'll have to create a replacement to UITabBarController yourself.

Comment: Instead of creating the standard "More" tab or a tabBar replacement he may also want to group two related tabs together with a custom made "More" view, it will avoid the plain tableView and could provide a better user experience.

Comment: Anything could provide a better user experience ;) I wonder what they were on when they decided that was the better solution (and that allowing 6-7 tabs was terrible and bad for you)...